# SQL Update Command updates all values in a column

Tags: php, sql, command, set

So in my website I'm trying to make a page where people can edit which URL is in a certain mySQL table, here is my code before I go any further (for at least one part of it)

```
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $title = $row['title'];
    $url=$row['url'];
    $id = $row['inid'];
    echo "<input type='button' id='delete' value='X' onclick='return Deleteqry($id)' />";
    echo "<form action='admin.php' method='POST'><input type='text' name='urledit' /><input type='submit' name='redit' /></form>";
    echo $title . '</br>';
    echo $url . '</br></br>';
            if(isset($_POST['redit']))
            {
                $newd = $_POST['urledit'];

                mysql_query("UPDATE `insects` SET url = '$newd' WHERE inid = $id ");
                header("location: admin.php");
            }
    }
```

Except the only problem is taht after they submit their value, it updates all the "url" rows in the table. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: change the single quotes around your table name to backticks

Comment: I assume the command $id=2 is intentional?  How many different inid values are in your table?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the single quotes around your table name to backticks and remove the single quotes from 2 since it is an integer.

Also check your database to make sure you have not inadvertently changed all values in that column to 2 when testing an earlier query.

Comment: But i think this is not the reason. because he said that all rows are updating. how is it possible? the query should update only the rows that have inid = 2. as a charecter or integer.. isnt it?

Comment: I think you are right. You may have inadvertently updated all values to 2 when you were testing an earlier query.

Answer (score 1):

If the row type for inid is int, remove the single quotes from the tablename, as well as from the 2 at the end, as it is an integer.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE insects SET url = '$newd' WHERE inid = 2 ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE 'insects' SET url = '$newd' WHERE inid = '2' ");
```

You are always updating the rows where inid=2, so i'm guessing all you urls in your db have inid with value '2'

Comment: Okay so the basic concept worked, but now when i Want to edit it for each value, I put the isset function inside my while loop (I'll edit my post to show you) and now its doing it again

Answer (score 0):

Brother,
 Did you chack your table?  are you using auto increment for `inid`.
 please check your table is `inid` has same values.

I didnt see any mistakes on your query.